# Is there any way to create a conditional constraint while using CBC solver with or-tools?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools, coin-or-cbc

Lets suppose I use BoolVars called 'x,y,z' in my MIP problem and I would like to set a contraint like :

```
 3x + 4y <= 5*z  only if z = 1
```

I would I do that using CBC solver in ortools library for python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no.
We are in the process of rewriting the linear solver wrapper to support these.

This being said, I do not know if they are supported by CBC. 
If your problem is purely integer, the CP-SAT solver supports implied constraints natively.

Comment: I think I might be able to add some changes to my model to make it purely integer. Thank you for your answer! It is really apreciated.

Comment: But I was wondering if CP-SAT has a Sum() function like CBC solver? And if not, how do I write my constraints.

Comment: Which programming language are you using ? I suggest you look at https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/README.md and the associated pages.   Short answer is yes.

Comment: I came across this answer while searching a similar problem, my problem is purely integers but I couldn't find proper documentation for using objective/cost function in CP-SAT

Comment: You can start by looking at https://developers.google.com/optimization and https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/README.md